# i3 3100T power consumption

Tags: processor, power

Has anyone information on the real-life power consumption of an Intel i3 7100T? I know that the thermal design power is rated 35W, but how much power does it need in idle or low workload situations?

I need this information since I want to compare this CPU to an Intel Pentium G4560, which has 19,5W in idle and 26W in low workload situations (according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9JplrjV5Fw)).

I want to configure a home server that will run 24/7, so power consumption is important to me.

Thanks in advance,
Lukas

Comment: possibly related: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/lga1151-cpu-lowest-power-consumption